# i am using scrapy for scraping. xpath is correct but not give content of tag

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy for scraping XPath is correct XPath work on the scrapy shell but in this code give none as output.I am fetching urls from google spread sheet.spread sheet fetched successfully but response in none.Give the following response:

```
2018-06-12 13:46:01 [oauth2client.client] INFO: Refreshing access_token
2018-06-12 13:46:01 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS    connection (1): spreadsheets.google.com
2018-06-12 13:46:02 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG:https://spreadsheets.google.com:443 "GET /feeds/spreadsheets/private/full HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2018-06-12 13:46:03 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://spreadsheets.google.com:443 "GET /feeds/worksheets/1oxVjCH2otn_OcS5PlogjsPd8fkDXEnI_4dWptACS4eU/private/full HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2018-06-12 13:46:03 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://spreadsheets.google.com:443 "GET /feeds/cells/1oxVjCH2otn_OcS5PlogjsPd8fkDXEnI_4dWptACS4eU/od6/private/full HTTP/1.1" 200 None
['7185297', 'http://macys.com/shop/product/polo-ralph-lauren-baseline-hat?ID=2606206', '24.99', '35', 'New', '19 Sep 16']
2018-06-12 13:46:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (301) <GET http://macys.com/shop/product/polo-ralph-lauren-baseline-hat?ID=2606206> (referer: None)
None

import scrapy

import gspread

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

class MacysSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'macys'
allowed_domains = ['macys.com']

def start_requests(self):
    scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("/home/prakher/cred.json", scope)
    gs = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    gsheet = gs.open("test")
    # worksheet=gsheet.sheet_by_index(0)
    wsheet = gsheet.worksheet("Sheet1")

    all_rows = wsheet.get_all_values()

    all_urls=all_rows[1:]
    #all_urls=['http://goodreads.com/quotes']
    for url in all_urls:
        print(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url[1], meta={
            'dont_redirect': True,
            'handle_httpstatus_list': [302, 200, 301]
        }, callback=self.parse)




def parse(self, response):
    print("Hi")
    res=response.xpath('.//div[@class="columns medium-10 medium-centered product-not-available-message"]/p/text()').extract_first()
    print(res)
```

Comment: It's likely that the site gives different responses for scrapy shell and your spider code. Check `response.status` in shell and in the code.

Comment: For scrapy shell response code is 200 and for spider reponse code is 301

Comment: And what if you omit `handle_httpstatus_list` from `yield scrapy.Request` statement?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that scrapy shell redirects you and your code does not, because you explicitly set `dont_redirect` to `True` and included `3xx` codes to `handle_httpstatus_list`:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url=url[1], meta={
    'dont_redirect': True,
    'handle_httpstatus_list': [302, 200, 301]
}, callback=self.parse)
```

Try to get rid of these parameters:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url=url[1], callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: I have already tried this, it does not work. Once check my code.

Comment: @PrakherAgarwal does it return 302 response status when you get rid of the parameters?

Comment: No, I got only 301 response status

Comment: @PrakherAgarwal that's strange. Scrapy should redirect if 301 response is returned.